# Best way to create dropdownlists in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a two db tables one is the table of categories the second is the table of category values.

For each category I need to create a dropdownlist with values of the second table.
The second step is to put these dynamically created dropdownlists in a component similar to a formview to update, delete update and get the SelectedValue from a GridView filled with a third db table.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: please be more specific with your question... do you want a dropdown textbox or radiobutton?  pick one.  also what does update, insert, select and delete have to do with your question

Comment: the dropdownlist is one of the types of control i have to put in the control but is not important i know how to do this, the update, select, insert, delete is fundamental because i need a component (formview, detailsview) to manage the SelectedIndex from a gridview

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you're getting the data it's hard to give a precise answer, but there are 2 broad approaches you could consider. A foreach loop to iterate through the categories, which passes the category id to a function that builds the drop down for that category.

```
foreach category in categories
{
  BuildDropDown(category.ID);
}

private void BuildDropDown(int id)
{
  var values = GetValuesByCategoryID(id)
  foreach value in values
  {
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(value, value.Id));
  }
}
```

or, the other approach would be to get all the data when you load up the page. If your data is in 2 tables then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblCategory AS C 
INNER JOIN tblCategoryValue AS CV ON CV.FKCategoryID = C.CategoryID
```

Then call that and iterate through tracking the CategoryID, when it changes it's time to emit a new drop down.